# styling TextInputLayout / TextInputEditText

Tags: android-layout

I wanted to use the TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText in my app and was looking for ways to style this. Now there are lost of paged when you start googling on it but it also seems some thinks have changed in the current android version.

Do not misunderstand the pages where very usefull but did not supply a complete answer.
For that reason i am posting my end result here so others may benefit.

Before i explain in the answer below i want to thank Dmytro on his blog [here](https://medium.com/omisoft/textinputlayout-styling-8b36a5e0d73c) as it was the most usefull.

Answer (score 0):

The answer.
I made my example very colorfull to make it easier to understand.
[image]

To get to this result i used the following in my layout. sorry that it is not code but a picture but i did this so you can see the actual color and not just my name for it
[image]

Not a color thing, but as you can see i set the app:errorEnabled to true. this is done so the space needed for the error is already reserved which means your layout wil not rescale when there is an error.

the last thing you need it the border_color.xml:

[image]

Play around with the option to see what they do.

The only thing i did not manage to do in the layout is to change the color of the selectionHandles. I did find a code solution for it but...i'll keep looking.